# Accepting SSH connections only from localhost

Tags: ssh, localhost, tor

I just installed SSH and I would like to set it up to only accept connections from localhost. I plan to point a .onion address to it so that I may connect to it from anywhere on any network.

Answer (score 19):

In the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file there are those fields :

```
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Change `#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` to `ListenAddress 127.0.0.1`, taking note to remove the leading `#`.

Then run `sudo reload ssh` and you will be able to connect only from localhost.

Comment: To reload ssh, run this command : `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

add the following line to the file `/etc/hosts.deny`:

```
sshd: ALL
```

add the following line to the file `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
sshd: localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

Plus you should read about [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables).

You can block connection to your host on port 22 via iptables:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
# iptables -I INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

And read about [TransparentProxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy).

Anyway solution with /etc/ssh/sshd_config, better.